# CTaskDialog hyperlinks in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, taskdialog

Hi I am using CTaskDialog class in my MFC application. I am trying to customize it.
In this if i want to add hyperlinks, as of now there is no specific provision for this. But to add the buttons we can use "AddCommandControl" and can handle the button.
If I want to implement similar to this AddHyperlinkControl and want to handle can any suggest how i can achieve it. My goal is I want to handle the click event of that hyperlink. Please share your suggestions if any one tried this.

Hi I am mainly looking for button alternative with hyperlink. Please share your suggestions.

Thanks a lot.
Haranadh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would want to have a hyperlinks in a dialog and would want to handle the click event on it, You should be using  SysLink common control (CLinkCtrl)... Check this out -> [SysLink common control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/dd450359.aspx)